# Using operators on a custom type in a lambda at compile time in C++

Tags: c++, lambda, constexpr

I have a class which I'd like to perform operations on at compile time. In the example below I have a simple struct `IntWrapper` with an overloaded `operator+`. Using this class in any normal context seems to work fine, but it fails when used inside a lambda, why?

```
struct IntWrapper
{
    consteval IntWrapper operator+(const IntWrapper& other) const
    {
        return { x + other.x };
    }

    int x;
};

int main()
{
    // Adding normally works just fine
    constexpr IntWrapper c1 = IntWrapper{ 1 } + IntWrapper{ 1 };

    auto adder = [](IntWrapper x) { return x + x; };

    // Using a lambda to add doesn't work
    constexpr IntWrapper c2 = adder(IntWrapper{ 1 });
}
```

How can I get this object to work, at compile time, inside the context of a lambda?

Comment: Can you define "fails" in more technical terms, like specific error messages?

Comment: For comparison: clang accepts, see [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/xKGYzhvaY). Cannot tell which one is correct, though.

Comment: Oh interesting, Clang 16.0.0 with c++2b fails to compile https://godbolt.org/z/djbxEKPGM

Comment: Is this fixed in C++23?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the old C++20 rules, `x + x` being `x.operator+(x)` must be a constant expression, since it calls a `consteval` function but is not inside a `consteval` function itself. It can't be a constant expression since it uses the function argument's values.

Make it be inside a `consteval` function:

```cpp
auto adder = [](IntWrapper x) consteval { return x + x; };
```

This is fixed with [P2564R3](https://wg21.link/P2564R3) so a compiler following the new rules (like clang 17) will compile this, even in C++20 mode.